Mtg: Electrostatic Field return to hand
Situation:
The Electrostatic Field is a creature.
In my turn I play the Artful Maneuver.
My opponent plays the Compelling Deterrence and returns the electrostatic field in my hand.
I know that his spell is over my spell in the stack, but is the ability of the electrostatic field still triggerd or not because it returns to my hand before my spell is spoken?
In the ruling on gathering.wizards is said:
Electrostatic Field's triggered ability resolves before the spell that caused it to trigger. It resolves even if that spell is countered.
But it’s not a counter spell to the spell it brings the creature back in my hand.

Although the linked question may give the answer in this case, I don't think it's quite a duplicate because of the wording in the question "is the ability of the electrostatic field still triggerd or not". That implies that either it's not clear to the asker that it would already have triggered, or that the asker thinks that being triggered is an ongoing state rather than a one-time event.

Standard terminology is that things are "on top" or "above" other things in the stack. Maybe it's just me, but it took me a few moments to parse the term "over". And spells "resolve", not "are spoken". While from the context, I can infer what you mean, this question relies quite heavily on the distinction between a spell being cast versus resolving, and the term "spoken" is extremely unclear as to what it means.

Electrostatic Field's triggered ability is triggered before your opponent ever casts Compelling Deterrence. An ability triggering is a thing that happens at a specific moment, abilities are not "still triggered" later on.


Casting Spells


601.2i Once the steps described in 601.2a–h are completed, effects that modify the characteristics of the spell as it’s cast are applied, then the spell becomes cast. Any abilities that trigger when a spell is cast or put onto the stack trigger at this time. If the spell’s controller had priority before casting it, they get priority.


So as soon as you finished casting Artful Maneuver, the ability triggered, and then went on the stack above Artful Maneuver, before your opponent had a chance to cast his spell. And as per the linked question, once that ability is on the stack, Electrostatic Field is no longer relevant.

113.7a Once activated or triggered, an ability exists on the stack independently of its source. Destruction or removal of the source after that time won’t affect the ability.

